Word Editor error 287 after upgrading to Windows 11
I have a company laptop that was on Windows 10 last week and is now on Windows 11 after the IT has upgraded it.
Some of the macros I wrote that were working on Windows 10 are not working now.
For instance, this macro generates an email template with content extracted from an Excel file using word editor.
Dim ola as object
set ola = outlook.application 
Dim Doc as word.document
Dim email as object
set email = ola.createitem(0)

email.display
Set doc = email.GetInspector.WordEditor

The code stops at
Set doc = email.GetInspector.WordEditor

with

run time error 287

The macro works on my colleague’s laptop that is on Windows 10.

searching for '[vba] error 287' (without the quotes) gives over 80 hits, Please check if any of them fits your situation.

For example, this answer looks plausible.
